# Echo not displaying my result/answer

Tags: php, lamp, php-7

I'am using php 7.0, apache2, mysql ver 14.14 distribution 5.6.17, and phpmyadmin 5.7

My php file for some reason will not display the value for variable $result. Whenever I try to use "echo" it wont display it. Not even another variable (sum).

My html file has following code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
<title>calculation form</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>


<body>

<form method="post" action="calculate.php">
<p>Value 1: <input type="text" name="val1" size="10"></p>
<p>Value 2: <input type="text" name="val2" size="10"></p>
<p>Calculation:<br>
<input type="radio" name="calc" value="add"> add<br>
<input type="radio" name="calc" value="subtract"> subtract<br>
<input type="radio" name="calc" value="multiply"> multiply<br>
<input type="radio" name="calc" value="divide"> divide
</p>
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Calculate"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

My php code has the following:

```
<?php

$sum = 0;

if(($_POST[val1] == "") || ($_POST[val2] == "") || ($_POST[calc] == ""))
{
    header("Location: calculate_form.html");
    exit;
}

if($_POST[calc] == "add")
{
    $result = $_POST[val1] + $_POST[val2];
}

if($_POST[calc] == "subtract")
{
    $result = $_POST[val1] - $_POST[val2];
}

if($_POST[calc] == "multiply")
{
    $result = $_POST[val1] - $_POST[val2];
}

if ($_POST[calc] == "divide") {
    $result = $_POST[val1] / $_POST[val2];
}

?>



<?php

echo $result;
echo $sum;

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to echo inside if condition or you have to set variable globally

```
<?php

    $sum = 0;

    if(($_POST['val1'] == "") || ($_POST['val2'] == "") || ($_POST['calc'] == ""))
    {
        header("Location: calculate_form.html");
        exit;
    }

    if($_POST['calc'] == "add")
    {
        $result = $_POST['val1'] + $_POST['val2'];
        echo $result;
    }

    if($_POST['calc'] == "subtract")
    {
        $result = $_POST['val1'] - $_POST['val2'];
        echo $result;
    }

    if($_POST['calc'] == "multiply")
    {
        $result = $_POST['val1'] - $_POST['val2'];
        echo $result;
    }

    if ($_POST['calc'] == "divide") {
        $result = $_POST['val1'] / $_POST['val2'];
        echo $result;
    }

    ?>
```

or else set like this

```
 if($_POST[calc] == "add")
    {
        $result = $_POST[val1] + $_POST[val2];
        $sum= $result;
    }
```

also yuo have error in `$_POST[val1]`

it should be  `$_POST['val1']`

**Updated with example**

```
<?php

    $sum = 0;
$_POST['val1']=5;
$_POST['val2']=10;
$_POST['calc']='add';
    if(($_POST['val1'] == "") || ($_POST['val2'] == "") || ($_POST['calc'] == ""))
    {
        header("Location: calculate_form.html");
        exit;
    }

    if($_POST['calc'] == "add")
    {
       $sum = $_POST['val1'] + $_POST['val2'];

    }

    if($_POST['calc'] == "subtract")
    {
      $sum = $_POST['val1'] - $_POST['val2'];

    }

    if($_POST['calc'] == "multiply")
    {
      $sum = $_POST['val1'] - $_POST['val2'];

    }

    if ($_POST['calc'] == "divide") {
       $sum = $_POST['val1'] / $_POST['val2'];

    }
echo $sum;
    ?>
```

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. It won't display anything.

Comment: plesase see  $_POST[val1] and it should be quoted in single quote  $_POST['val1']

Comment: Ok for some reason when i added echo to all conditional statements it worked. Thanks alot bro. I also tried initializing the variable in the beginning. Smdh why didn't i understand that earlier....so embarassing. Thanks alot once again :)

Comment: I will. It gives me 5 minutes before I accept answer. :)

Comment: @JosephBourne.okay